# Are Firestore snapshot listeners invoked on auth state changes by default?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to debug something and I could not find the culprit until I realized that Firestore snapshot listeners were calling themselves whenever a user signed out. Is this indeed what is happening? Does a snapshot listener call itself when an authenticated user becomes null? What is the purpose of this unexpected behavior and can we disable it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a snapshot listener attached to a query that is authorized by security rules, and the rules say the user must be signed in, then the listener will generate an error if the user is no longer signed in.  This is expected, and necessary to tell the client app that the query is no longer valid.

Comment: The query in question has no rules about reads, any auth state can perform it. Is this snapshot listener still supposed to call when a user signs out? Seems out of place.

Comment: Maybe you would like to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, so that we can try it out for ourselves?

Comment: Just attach any plain snapshot listener on any query without any rules and sign out and you'll see it called. However, I just noticed that if I include metadata changes in the listener, the listener **will** fire when the user signs out, but if I exclude metadata changes, the listener **will not** fire when the user signs out. I certainly would have never figured this behavior out on my own without monkey testing. I'm sure there's a good explanation for it.